# What should be the dimensions of a Fourier Transformed image?

Tags: image-processing, fft, fourier-transform

I have applied Fourier Transform to the following image.

[image]

I have downloaded this image from the Internet. I re-sized (without maintaining the aspect ratio) it using MS Paint application of Win7 to make it 512x256.

Then I have used two applications to observe its Fourier Transformed appearance.

[IPLab](http://www.aforgenet.com/projects/iplab/downloads.html) gives the following output:

[image]

[ImageJ2-20160205](http://imagej.net/Downloads) gives the following output:

[image]

As you can see, the first output is a 512x256 image. The second one is a 512x512 image.

**Why are those outputs different?**

**How would they effect processing of an image?**

Comment: Without seeing the details of the transform, I would assume the second case is zero-padded out to the 512 dimension. If this is the case, this will result in interpolated samples to the original image when you do the IFFT; so a form of upsampling. Have you tried to take the IFFT of the second image using IPLab?

Comment: @dan boschen, not yet. But, now I would.

Comment: @laurent duval, hmm.. What does that indicate?

Comment: That this is is not the size that only matters:) You have coloured images. Try redo on their grayscale version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Looking at the source code for `ImageJ`](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/plugins/download/FFT_.java) I see:

```
public void run(ImageProcessor ip) {
    boolean inverse;
    if (!powerOf2Size(ip)) {
        IJ.error("A square, power of two size image or selection\n(128x128, 256x256, etc.) is required.");
        return;
    }
    ImageProcessor fht  = (ImageProcessor)imp.getProperty("FHT");
    if (fht!=null) {
        ip = fht;
        inverse = true;
    } else
        inverse = false;
    ImageProcessor ip2 = ip.crop();
    if (!(ip2 instanceof FloatProcessor)) {
        ImagePlus imp2 = new ImagePlus("", ip2);
        new ImageConverter(imp2).convertToGray32();
        ip2 = imp2.getProcessor();
    }
    fft(ip2, inverse);
}
```

which suggests that some parts of the code expect a) the image size to be a power of 2 and b) that the image is square.  Perhaps some part of the code you are using is enforcing this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a third different output. So I have tried to perform an FFT with Matlab, on four versions of your image:

- the grayscale version of the colored image,
- the red, green, and blue channels.

I do get  the following, with $512\times256$ size, in a $\log$ scale.

[image: Fourier Grayscale RGB]

If as suggested by @Peter K. you zero-pad below, with $512\times512$ size, one gets:

[image: Fourier Grayscale RGB padded]

Looks like  the FFT of the Red component, padded.
If you have the opportunity to do other tests, we can settle this riddle